# not able to open PuTTy key generator

Tags: putty

I am really new to Putty and Puttykey generator as I am trying to setup EC2 on AWS. I have managed to install PuTTy on my Mac, and PuTTy works fine, but every time I click on PuTTykey Generator I see a message (please see the snap attached) and no pop up window. how do I get it to work? I have Mac Mojave.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the reason why you use `puttygen` is to generate the ssh-key pair especially on windows systems. You don't generally need to use putty key generator on mac since Mac OS has a built-in command-line SSH client known as Terminal.

To use terminal, go to Finder and then click the menus `Go -> utilities` from the top menu. After that find the terminal which supports SSH connections to remote servers.

You can run `ssh-keygen` to generate an ssh key pair.

```
ssh-keygen
```

reference (how to use ssh-keygen to generate a keypair):

https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-openssh/

I am not sure about the reason why you are trying to use puttygen through.

If you simply like to login to your ec2 instance via ssh (using the keypair from ec2), you can use ssh command as below.

```
ssh -i `~/Downloads/my.pem` ec2-user@[ip-address]
```

by the way, The reason why you are seeing an output like the one you shared is, when you run `puttygen` is, it's a command line utility and it's expecting some mandatory command line arguments to be passed.

Comment: why do you want to use puttygen

Comment: is that what you were looking for

Comment: hi @Arun K thanks for your reply. that was most helpful and yes I am trying to log on to my EC2 instance using the tutorial from this YouTube  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE303yFWfV4&t=247s) 4:16 to 6:00. I have downloaded the key for my EC2 instance but how do I use your command. to create .ppk format from the .pem file that I have downloaded. i.e. I understand that putty gen is simply converting the key in a format that can be used by PuTTy. (4:16 to 6:00 in that clip)

Comment: btw had to repost my question here https://superuser.com/questions/1513347/not-able-to-open-putty-key-generator